# In Node.js, is it possible to tell where a watched file was moved to?

Tags: node.js, filesystemwatcher

[fs.watch](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs.watch) provides only two possible event types: `'rename'` and `'change'`. Both renaming a file (e.g. using `mv`) and deleting it (e.g. using `rm`) cause `fs.watch` to report a `'rename'` event.

After a file is moved, `fs.watch` will continue to report events from it (unless you explicitly close the [FSWatcher](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs.FSWatcher)). When that happens, I'd like to know where the file has moved to.

Is there any way to do this, short of touching every file on the system in turn to see when a `'change'` event is fired?

Comment: Perhaps you could do something with the filename in the callback? Linux and Windows are supposed to return a filename with the event.

Comment: @ChrisBiscardi I'm a Mac guy, so the filename is always `null` on my system; I haven't tested elsewhere. I'd be curious to know what the `filename` argument is under Linux/Windows when a file is moved (or deleted).

Comment: Yea, I'm a mac guy too. I just tested some stuff on a nix server but when I mv'd a file no event was fired. Maybe a bug in v0.6.1? anyway, all you get from fs.watch is the filename, no path. fs.watchFile returns a stat object though, could be useful.

Comment: Right, `fs.watchFile` just fires a `stat` at the given path every `interval` milliseconds; if you move a file to or from that path, `watchFile` doesn't care.

Comment: Apparently kqueue (used on OSX) [doesn't offer a way to detect when a file has moved](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/kevent.2.html). On Linux, [inotify](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-inotify/?ca=drs-) offers events for path changes, windows [does too](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/deps/uv/src/win/fs-event.c) but you can't get to the new path...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks impossible until node either implements an interface to get file names from a file descriptor (so you could just keep a fd and get the name from there on `rename`), or gives back the path/filename reliably along the FSWatcher events.

A workaround to this would be to create a temporary hard link to the target file via `fs.link` , then you can get at the file even after changes, though you won't be able to retrieve it's new name.

It's interesting that EventMachine has the same issue: http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org/EventMachine/FileWatch.html#M000291

Comment: Thanks, Ricardo. I've accepted this answer because it partially answered my question: Using `fs.link` does allow me to distinguish between a rename and a deletion. It looks like that's as much as I can hope to do, within the bounds of Node's API.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you would have to look at the original stat of the file and see the `inode` which is the identifier of the file. If the file did not move from one partition/filesystem/drive to another (which would actually have to be a copy-then-delete-original operation), then the `inode` would be the same.

Unfortunately, there is usually no lookup table of `inode`s to get their new name/location. You would have to systematically search the whole system, which might not be so bad assuming you can look at likely places first. or if you can search a limited area only.

You can use a temporary hard link (Ricardo's idea) to detect if it is deleted instead of moved. The number of links counter would change from 1 to 2 when you create your hard link, and would change from 2 back to 1 when the counterpart to your temporary hard link is deleted. If it is deleted, you have no need to look for the file's destination.

If there are only, say a few thousand files in this area, the solution here should work very well, if there are more, depending on your system, it might work, but there might be a delay.

If you wish to decrease the delay, you can have an SQL database of files that you already know the `inode`s for. For example, `/folder/filea` and `/folder/fileb` Both exist with different `inode`s. When `fileb` is moved to `filec`, you have no need to `stat` `filea` looking for the `inode` because you already looked it up previously. This logic should dramatically reduce the number of `stat` commands necessary. However, if `filea` is deleted and `fileb` is moved into `filea`s place, this dramatic reduction method would find no results, in which case you would have to fall back to searching the entire working directory.

You do still have the option of ensuring that OS folders like `/etc` or `/dev`. are only used as a last resort. Which you may never have to search, assuming you can detect deletion using the temporary hard link.

How big is your working area? Do you know for certain whether the file will always be moved from one place to another within a certain working folder? Additional details on your problem environment would be helpful.